# Configure JRebel with Jboss 4.3.2.GA

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, jrebel

I am trying to configure JRebel to be used with my currently existing Java EE application on JBoss 4.3.2.GA and Eclipse Ganymede .
I am following http://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel-reference-manual/server.html?source=eclipse-config#server-4.6.11.

But it says to use command file instead of run.bat. Please provide some idea about how to implement the command line in the curently existing script run.bat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you start the server from the IDE, you do not need to write your own script to start the container with JRebel. Instead, you can just click JRebel checkbox in the server configuration tab, as shown in  https://manuals.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/ide/eclipse.html#server-configuration

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am not starting server through the IDE but standalone.  I have a run.bat for my server but to add JRebel configuration to it is creating problems  for me....

Comment: Then it is just enough to include -javaagent:/path/to/jrebel.jar to JAVA_OPTIONS. Just use the example as described in the manual you have referred to, and copy the snippet into your own script, say run-with-jrebel.bat - as you can see it calls run.bat at the end

Comment: There is a issue ... I have a simple program... not used any server... but using JRebel agent in debug config in Eclipse Ganymede to reload class in case of changes made during Debugging.But when i add a sysout statement .. it gives me a obselete methods on the stack error... HOW TO RESOLVE THIS?

Comment: Just ignore the message and press "Continue"